# C++ multi threaded scheduling application issues

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc, scheduled-tasks

> **Background**

I am maintaining a Windows MFC C++ multi threaded job scheduling application. Users will schedule tasks to run from their local computer. Inactive users will automatically transfer their tasks to active users.

> **Issues**

Some jobs are failing to run. It is usually the same jobs, but not always the same jobs. There are two jobs that very often fail. They have varying expected run times. They are both scheduled to run on non-overlapping time intervals with one another.

> **Method for creating processes:**

The location of the job is fed into the following function:

```
 int VirtualGridDriver::RunApplicationAsProcessWithExitCode(CString cmdLine)
 {
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation = {0};
    STARTUPINFO startupInfo                = {0};
    startupInfo.cb                         = sizeof(startupInfo);
    int nStrBuffer                         = cmdLine.GetLength() + 50;


   //Create the process
    BOOL result = CreateProcess(NULL, cmdLine.GetBuffer(nStrBuffer), 
                                NULL, NULL, FALSE, 
                                NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NO_WINDOW, 
                                NULL, NULL, &startupInfo, &processInformation);
    cmdLine.ReleaseBuffer();


    if (!result)
    {
      //CreateProcess() failed
      //Get the error from the system
       LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
       DWORD dw = GetLastError();
       FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, 
                     NULL, dw, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf, 0, NULL);

      //Display the error
       CString strError = (LPTSTR) lpMsgBuf;

      //Free resources created by the system
       LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);

      //We failed.
       return 1;
    }
    else
    {
      //Successfully created the process.  Wait for it to finish.
       WaitForSingleObject( processInformation.hProcess, INFINITE );
       DWORD B;
       GetExitCodeProcess (processInformation.hProcess, &B);

      //Close the handles.
       CloseHandle( processInformation.hProcess );
       CloseHandle( processInformation.hThread );

       int ret = int(B);

      //We succeeded.
       return ret;
    }
 }
```

The failed jobs return with exit code 1. Can anyone identify possible issues? If not, can someone provide some issues I may consider looking more deeply into? Could this be a multithreaded issue?

Comment: 'The failed jobs return with exit code 1' - sounds reasonable.  What did those jobs say about why they failed?  What did they log?

Comment: Note that an exit code of 1 is not necessarily an error - it's defined by the process you're spawning. Zero indicating success is a convention, not a requirement. Are you sure that a non-zero exit code is not normal behavior for those jobs?

Comment: We cannot see the code that presumably fails. Process exit codes are meaningless without knowing which process returned it, and how that specific process signals errors. The code you posted is ok-ish, with the exception of calling `GetLastError` too late, and truncating `cmdLine` when calling `ReleaseBuffer`.